# Quotient group of a semidirect product.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

Let $G=AB$ be a semidirect product of groups $A$ and $B$ with $B\lhd G$ and $A\cap B=\{e\}$. Let $N=[A,B]$ be the subgroup generated by commutators $[a,b]=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, $a\in A, b\in B$.

1.) Show that $N$ is normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $B$.

Proof: Let $n\in N$ and then for any $g\in G$ we have $gng^{-1}=gng^{-1}(n^{-1}n)=(gng^{-1}n^{-1})n.$ Thus $gng^{-1}\in N$ for all $g\in G$. Further, for any $n\in N$ there exist $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $n=aba^{-1}b^{-1}=(aba^{-1})b^{-1}\in B.$ Thus $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $B$.

EDIT: We want to show that for an arbitrary element $n\in N$ and an arbitrary element $g\in G$ that $gng^{-1}\in N$. Every $n\in N$ has the form $n=[a_1,b_1][a_2,b_2]\cdots[a_k,b_k]$ so that
$$
\begin{align*}
gng^{-1}&=g([a_1,b_1][a_2,b_2]\cdots[a_k,b_k])g^{-1}\\
&=g[a_1,b_1]g^{-1}g[a_2,b_2]g^{-1}g\cdots g^{-1}g[a_k,b_k]g^{-1}\\
&=(g[a_1,b_1]g^{-1})(g[a_2,b_2]g^{-1})\cdots (g[a_k,b_k]g^{-1}).
\end{align*}
$$
Thus it suffices to show that $g[a,b]g^{-1}\in N$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
g[a,b]g^{-1}&=g(aba^{-1}b^{-1})g^{-1}\\
&=ga(g^{-1}g)b(g^{-1}g)a^{-1}(g^{-1}g)b^{-1}g^{-1}\\
&=(gag^{-1})(gbg^{-1})(ga^{-1}g^{-1})(gb^{-1}g^{-1})\\
&=(gag^{-1})(gbg^{-1})(gag^{-1})^{-1}(gbg^{-1})^{-1}\\
&=[gag^{-1},gbg^{-1}]
\end{align*}
$$
Clearly $gng^{-1}$ is a commutator, but is it a commutator in $N$? Since $B\lhd G$, then $gbg^{-1}\in B$, but what can I say about $gag^{-1}$? I need to be able to say that $gag^{-1}\in A$ to complete this part of the proof, right?

2.) Prove that $G/N\cong A\times B/N$.

Now I am stuck. All I seem to know right now is that $G/N$ is going to be abelian, so it makes sense to find a direct product structure for $G/N$.

Comment: Hint: Can you find a map $G/N\rightarrow (A\times B)/N$?  Since $G$ is a semidirect product, there is a natural map (set theoretically).  Then, prove that this map is constant on equivalence classes, is a group homomorphism, etc.

Comment: Your proof that $N$ is normal is incomplete. Starting from $gng^{-1}=(gng^{-1}n^{-1}) n$, to conclude that this is in $N$ you must show that $gng^{-1}n^{-1}$ is in $N$, but you haven't shown that. Notice that you have not used the hypothesis that $n \in [A,B]$.

Comment: You will need to use (several times) the fact that since $G$ is a semidirect product of $A$ and $B$, every element $g$ of $G$ can be written as $g=ab$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.  This will help in the issue that @LeeMosher mentioned as well as the second part.

Comment: Also note that a generic $n \in N$ is a *product* of commutators, not a single one. Thus $n = [a_1,b_1]\cdots[a_k,b_k]$ rather than $n = aba^{-1}b^{-1}$.

Comment: You are actually more stuck than you think. There is no reason why $G/N$ should be abelian, as you have not taken the full commutator subgroup.

Comment: This rose to the top again, so I edited to add the group theory tag, and clarified the definition of $[A,B]$.