# Class number of cubic subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ is 1 mod 3?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $K$ be the cubic subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ for a prime $p\equiv 1\bmod 3$. Numerical data suggests that $h_K\equiv 1\bmod 3$.

Does anyone know if this is true in general and how one can prove this? I can exclude some integers as special cases by considering the Hilbert class field $H$ of $K$, but I could not find a general pattern.

For example, if we would have $h_K=2$, then $H/\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension of degree $6$. But then $G=\mathrm{Gal}(H/\mathbb{Q})$ is cyclic as $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is normal, which would force $H\subset\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ as well by Kronecker-Weber. This contradicts that $H/K$ is unramified however since $p$ is totally ramified in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: An elementary exercise: if $C$ is an abelian group with an action of $G = \mathbf{Z}/3 \mathbf{Z}$, then either $|C| \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ or $C_G$ is non-trivial. So the general case is the same as the special case --- if $|C| \not \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ (where $C$ is the class group), then the genus field would be non-trivial. But the genus field is trivial.

Comment: Ah, I though that you would need to use the classification of groups of order $3h_K$ for a given $h_K$, but that is not needed at all :) I checked the details and it indeed all follows straightforwardly. Thanks you!

Comment: @Tim.ev  One little question. Why does $|C|\neq 1 \pmod{3}$ implies genus field of $K$ is non-trivial.

Comment: Dear pisco, well in any case, the group $\mathrm{Gal}(H/\mathbb{Q})$ is a semi-direct product of $Cl_K$ with $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ and the natural action (to see that $0\to Cl_K\to \mathrm{Gal}(H/\mathbb{Q})\to \mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})\to 0$ splits consider a non-trivial inertia group, then check that the action corresponds with the natural one). Now the invariants of $Cl_K$ under $G=\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ as a subgroup in this semi-direct product is normal and with Abelian quotient, hence the corresponding fixed field lies in the genus field.

Comment: @Tim.ev  Thank you :). I am able to follow until you claim that the invariants of $Cl_K$ has abelian quotient. Why this is true? If $$0\to K\to G\to Q\to 0$$ is split, $K$ abelian, $Q$ is cyclic,  then the invariants of $K$ under action of $G$ does not seem to contain the commutator subgroup $[G:G]$, so quotient is not abelian. The fact that $h_K\neq 1 \pmod{3}$ implies $|K\cap C(G)|>1$ (where $C(G)$ is the center of $G$), but I am not sure this relates to abelian quotient. Could you explain further why quotient is abelian?

Comment: I've given it some thought but I have to agree with you... I don't see why the quotient should be Abelian. @Infinity, can you maybe explain why $h_K\neq 1\bmod 3$ implies a non-trivial genus field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the hint by @Infinity needs further clarification. Below is a complete solution, but still follows closely the hint.

---

> Let $p,q$ be primes such that $p\equiv 1 \pmod{q}$, let $K$ be the
>   degree $q$ subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$. Let $h$ denotes the class
>   number of $K$, then $h \equiv 1\pmod{q}$.

*Proof:* A large part of the argument is group-theoretical.

Let $H$ denote the Hilbert class field of $K$, $G=\text{Gal}(H/\mathbb{Q}), N = \text{Gal}(H/K), Q=\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$, then
$$0\to N\to G\to Q\to 0$$ is exact, it splits by considering a inertia field. $N$ has a $\mathbb{Z}[Q]$-module structure induced from the sequence. Consider $N$ under the action of $Q$, orbits of size $1$ corresponds to elements in $N^Q$ (elements of $N$ invariant under $Q$), so
$$h = |N| \equiv |N^Q| \pmod{q}$$

It suffices to show that $|N^Q|=1$. 
Writing $N$ in addition and $Q$ in multiplication, the action determines $G= N\rtimes Q$ via $$(a,x)(b,y) = (a+xb,xy)\qquad a,b\in N, x,y\in Q$$

Now the commutator $[N,Q]$ [satisfies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1674504) $[N,Q]\subset N$ and
$G/[N,Q] \cong Q\times (N/[N,Q])$,
therefore $G/[N,Q]$ is abelian. Since $K$ is ramified at only one prime, $[N,Q] = N$ (by considering an inertia field). On the other hand, 
$(a,1)(0,x)(a,1)^{-1}(0,x)^{-1} = ((1-x)a,1)$.

If $Q=\langle \theta \rangle$ and $I=(1-\theta)$ is an ideal inside the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[Q]$, then $IN=[N,Q]=N$. [Nakayama's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama%27s_lemma) says there exists $r\in \mathbb{Z}[Q]$ such that 
$r\equiv 1 \pmod{I}$ and $rN=0$. Write $r = f(\theta)(1-\theta) + 1$, where $f$ is a polynomial, for $a\in N^Q$, $a-\theta a=0$, so
$$0 = ra = f(\theta)(1-\theta)a + a = a$$
hence $N^Q$ is trivial, completing the proof.

---

Alternatively, as pointed out by @franz lemmermeyer, $N^Q$ is the ambiguous class group of $K/\mathbb{Q}$, so by [ambiguous class number formula](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.1071.pdf), it is trivial.

Comment: This is great, thank you!