# There exists imaginary quadratic extension which trivialized 2-part of ideal class group

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, ideal-class-group

Let $p$ be a negative prime number such that $p \equiv 5\pmod 8$.

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$ and denote its ideal class group by $Cl_K$.
I aim to prove that $Cl_K[2] := \{a \in Cl_K \mid 2a = 0\}$ is trivial.

In this context, $p$ and $2$ are unramified in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})/\mathbb{Q}$ because one can verify that the corresponding local field extension is unramified.

**Given this information on ramification, how can we conclude that $Cl_K[2] = 1$?**

Remarks:

1.A similar question is discussed at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141150/2-class-group-of-a-quadratic-imaginary-extension, but it lacks detailed answers to this specific question.

2.The concept of the "2-Hilbert class field" may be key to this question. If it can be shown that the 2-Hilbert class field of $K$ is $K$ itself, then we have our conclusion.

3.This formula follows from 'genus theory', but what I'm seeking is to understand this formula in terms of class field theory or ramification theory.

Comment: Try D. A. Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms. For positive forms, the form class group and ideal class group coincide.

Comment: This is equivalent to prove class number is odd. This follows from genera theory. Alternatively, a [purely group-theorectic argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2745340) also works: for an odd prime $p$, the degree $2$ subfield of the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ always has odd class number, this includes your case.